# I want to know working of sonarqube

Tags: eclipse, static-analysis, sonarqube, code

I install both SonarQube and sonar-runner. And I want to know how to start working. My project uses PHP language. So I want to check the code analysis of my project. But how to get started working?

Is Eclipse is needed for SonarQube?

Should we just add a file like `sonar-runner-properties` into the local project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the step-by-step procedure to perform the scenario:

- Setup a Jenkins server if already not using.
- Goto plugin-manager of Jenkins to install “SonarQube Plugin”.
- Goto “System-configuration” of Jenkins to provide “SonarQube”
  server’s details
- Create a Jenkins job and choose one source code management option
  (say git).
- Under build, add “Execute Shell” as build step and write commands to
  run unit tests.
- Add “Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis” as another build step and
  add below lines to “Analysis properties” block:

  ```
  sonar.projectKey=App Name- Any Identifier
  sonar.projectName=Project1
  sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
  sonar.projectDescription=Static analysis for the AppName
  sonar.sources=path/to/code/src, path/to/code/grails-app
  sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath=path/to/code/target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
  sonar.language=grvy
  sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
  ```

This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ihh3K00hV_k) guides us in triggering a Sonar Project from within Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there should be some thing or some one to push data to sonar qube. In my project i use Jenkins to push data to sonar qube.
Seems to be in you case you are trying to use Eclips to push data to sonar qube.
So please refer the below video
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QGOI_dkHLM&t=4s

Comment: please tell How to integrate with jenkins ? I want to use jenkins

Comment: Download jenkins and set up jenkins server.its a website where you can progrmaticaly add all your sonar scripts.

Comment: But I want to test in my local project. Is there any git repository needed in jenkins ? I don't have access permission in jenkins. so how should I check my code.

Comment: Then make a local jenkins  server on your own PC